# jQuery nesting $(this) fail inside complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I have a translation function using JSON

```
var json = $.getJSON("localization/translate.json", function (word) {
    $.each(word, function () {
        data = this;
        $(".translate").each(function (i, el) {
            var translation = $(el).attr("data-translate");
            if (translation === data.en) {
                $(el).fadeTo(500, 0, function () {
                    $(el).delay(600).html(data.en).fadeTo(500, 1);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`data` inside the `fadTo(function(data))` only show the last data value in the json, instead of value of each json value.

if I do

```
if(translation===data.en) {
    $(el).fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
            // move it to outside of this function.                             
    });
    $(el).html(data.en);
    $(el).fadeTo(500, 1);
}
```

than this is okay, but it will fire the html text change, before it completely fade to transparent.

Answer (score 4):

```
var data = this;
```

Use a local variable, not a global one, then you might see local results instead of global ones ;)

Comment: thank you, I have always thought var declaration is not important.